# Getting kernel crashes at startup and with any attempt at evaluation

Tags: warning-messages, installation

I just installed Mathematica. Everything worked fine and I am able to open a notebook, but when I try to calculate simple things (e.g., calculating the sum of 2 + 2) it says "running" for a few seconds then beeps and stopps the calculation. The output is: "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation". The same beep occurs when I open Mathematica, but there is no error message. I tried both restarting the application and  my computer. I also tried reinstalling Mathematica. I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 12.0. The Wolfram Kernel or the Math Kernel are both crashing immediately after launching.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? And what OS?

Comment: Mathematica 12.0  and Windows 10

Comment: Obviously it's difficult to give you concrete suggestions, but one thing to try is going to the installation directory (probably `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0`) and trying to launch a kernel there with `math.exe`.

Comment: Ok- I found the math.exe, but when i launch it, it closes automatically 3 seconds later